# Issues with Ignite benchmark

Tags: ignite

I am getting below error while running benchmark test using yardstick with default settings.

It is a standalone setup.

[root@db3 ~]# ./bin/benchmark-run-all.sh config/benchmark-sample.properties

<17:26:41> Failed to set up benchmark drivers (will shutdown and exit).
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1922)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1235)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1787)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1711)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1141)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:639)
at org.apache.ignite.IgniteSpring.start(IgniteSpring.java:65)
at org.apache.ignite.yardstick.IgniteNode.start(IgniteNode.java:220)
at org.apache.ignite.yardstick.IgniteAbstractBenchmark.setUp(IgniteAbstractBenchmark.java:64)
at org.apache.ignite.yardstick.cache.IgniteCacheAbstractBenchmark.setUp(IgniteCacheAbstractBenchmark.java:107)
at org.yardstickframework.BenchmarkDriverStartUp.main(BenchmarkDriverStartUp.java:130)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=org.apache.ignite.marshaller.MarshallerUtils$1@1eff3cfb], reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, soLinger=5, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null, skipAddrsRandomization=false]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:280)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:985)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1917)
... 10 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to join node (Incompatible data region configuration [region=DEFAULT, locNodeId=8c2b6d02-01b3-4c22-8ad2-67c0c5f9ec4e, isPersistenceEnabled=true, rmtNodeId=4011d970-ae2d-4116-bb85-4311195c88a8, isPersistenceEnabled=false])
at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.checkFailedError(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2047)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:1174)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:445)
at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2149)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:277

Comment: Hi, please place the code/error message in a code block. This makes it more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (Incompatible data region configuration [region=DEFAULT,
> locNodeId=8c2b6d02-01b3-4c22-8ad2-67c0c5f9ec4e,
> isPersistenceEnabled=true,
> rmtNodeId=4011d970-ae2d-4116-bb85-4311195c88a8,
> isPersistenceEnabled=false]) at

You have different persistence configurations for your nodes therefore they won't join each other according to the above error.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is working now